# Python Gekko Differential Equation Solution wrt Distance, not Time

Tags: python, ode, gekko

I need to solve a differential equation for a plug flow chemical reactor with respect to distance, not time. Gekko uses `m.time` to define the time horizon and `y.dt()` to use `dy/dt` in equations. Is it possible to covert to `m.distance` and `y.dx()` instead to make the problem easier to read for problems that integrate wrt distance?

Here is an attempt:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

m = GEKKO()
k = 10
m.distance = np.linspace(0,20,100)

y = m.Var(value=5)
t = m.Param(value=m.time)
m.Equation(k*y.dx()==-t*y)
m.options.IMODE=4
m.solve(disp=False)

plt.plot(m.distance,y.value)
plt.xlabel('distance')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\johnh\Desktop\test1.py", line 11, in <module>
    m.Equation(k*y.dx()==-t*y)
  File "C:\Users\johnh\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gekko\gk_operators.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: dx. Did you mean: 'dt'?
```

I don't need to solve a Partial Differential Equation (PDE) for a dynamic simulation of the plug flow reactor, only solve a steady-state concentration profile along the reactor. What is an easy way to redefine Gekko in terms of distance and make the model more readable?

Comment: I've never heard of GEKKO but two thoughts: (1) what if you change `t = m.Param(value=m.time)` to `x = m.Param(value=m.distance)`? or (2) forgo readability and just call your distance time if you don't have both quantities so `m.time = np.linspace(0,20,100)`

Answer (score 0):

Gekko can integrate with respect to time or distance (or both) but the naming is built for time. One idea to make it more readable is to use the built-in names, but create a copy of `m.time` as `m.distance` and a `der()` function such as:

```py
# redefine time basis as distance
m.time = np.linspace(0,20,100)
m.distance = m.time
def der(v):
    return v.dt()
```

Here is a more readable version that clarifies integration with respect to distance versus time.

[image: Integrate Distance]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

m = GEKKO()

# redefine time basis as distance
m.time = np.linspace(0,20,100)
m.distance = m.time
def der(v):
    return v.dt()

k = 10
y = m.Var(value=5)
x = m.Param(value=m.distance)
m.Equation(k*der(y)==-x*y)
m.options.IMODE=4
m.solve(disp=False)

plt.plot(m.distance,y.value)
plt.xlabel('distance')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```